# How to delete my contents from Ubuntu One before the shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu-one, downloads, contacts

Since Ubuntu one closes I want to delete all files and download all contacts.

How can I do that?

Do I need to something else after all data are removed from the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

All the files will be deleted from everywhere with the shut down.

As for contacts, you can go to the contacts website and delete them yourself (those won't be deleted, as U1DB will continue to run).